# excel averaging every 10 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a big data set which has about 9000 rows. I have a few variables for every year from 1960 onwards, and I need to average them in ten year bins. So I have something like:

```
1    
2    
3    
4    
2    
3    
4    
5
```

Now I need to average the first ten rows, then the next ten, and so on, for all 9000-odd rows. I can do that, but then I get all these rows averaged in the middle which I don't need, and I can't go about deleting those many rows. There has to be an easy way to do this, surely?

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Suppose your data starts from `A1`. Try this one in `B1`:

`=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,1+10*(ROW()-ROW($B$1))):INDEX(A:A,10*(ROW()-ROW($B$1)+1)))`

and drag it down.

- in `B1` it would be `=AVERAGE(A1:A10)`
- in `B2` it would be `=AVERAGE(A11:A20)`
- in `B3` it would be `=AVERAGE(A21:A30)`

and so on.

**General case**

If your data starts from `An` (where `n` is `2`,`3`,`4`,...), use this one:

`=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,n+10*(ROW()-ROW($B$1))):INDEX(A:A,n-1+10*(ROW()-ROW($B$1)+1))`

where you should change `n` to `2`,`3`,`4`,...

Comment: thanks! This works...but what if my data starts at A2?

Comment: see my formula below for general case (change `n` to `2`), so formula would be: `=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,2+10*(ROW()-ROW($B$1))):INDEX(A:A,1+10*(ROW()-ROW($B$1)+1))` :)

Comment: @DmitryPavliv, thank you for your answer. It's about 10 years later but when I apply this formula I get an error message that says "we found a problem with your formula". my data starts at BA2 and I want the result to show starting from BB2. I assume it is either because of my regional excel or because of an excel version. I am using the 2013 version. Your help is very much appreciated.