# Excel - Average every 3 rows AND insert answer every 3 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Overall problem: I want to be able to create a column (M) in an existing table that will average three values from column L and insert it in an *adjacent* cell.

Example:

```
  Row          I              J            K             L        M
   1     [Sample number]  [Replicate]  [Hours Exposed]  [YI]   [AVERAGE YI]
   2           1              1             0            12       13
   3           1              2             0            13    
   4           1              3             0            14
   5           2              1             0            10       11
   6           2              2             0            11
   7           2              3             0            12
```

Additional context if helpful: Chemistry data. The goal is to average the results from testing done in triplicate to get an overall value for a particular sample. Also want to be able to set up the database so that as additional data is added everything auto-calculates,and I can pull from it to create PivotCharts

This answer ([excel averaging every 10 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878018/excel-averaging-every-10-rows)) was *almost* exactly what I need, the formula works perfectly, but it inserts the answer in sequential cells down (B1, B2, B3) so my "average" column doesn't line up with the relevant sample

This answer ([How to find the average of every six cells in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162208/how-to-find-the-average-of-every-six-cells-in-excel?noredirect=1&lq=1_)) almost worked as well, with some changes to match my inputs, but I have a header row so everything starts at row 2 and for some reason that breaks the math. All the generated values are wrong because they're shifted by one cell and I haven't been able to figure out how to tell it "start at L2, not L1"

Comment: Try `=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,3)=0,AVERAGE(INDEX(L:L,ROW()-2):INDEX(L:L,ROW())),"")` - This may actually not work as it puts the value in the third cell in the range and not the first cell in the range of three

Comment: I would have said =IF(MOD(ROW()+1,3)=0,AVERAGE(L2:L4),"") would be enough, the rest works by relative addressing as the formula is pulled down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()+1,3)=0,AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1,4)),0,0,3,1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi QHarr! Tried the modification, looks like this just pulls the value in L for Replicate 2 of each sample and inserts it into column M, rather than taking an average of all 3. It just trickily appears to be right using the simplified values in my example where the average = that middle number

Comment: I don't know what Replicate 2 is but it takes the average of every 3 rows starting from row 2.

Comment: So what I'm getting is that it's calculating the average of (5.55, 5.17, 5.42) to be 5.17 (so pulling the 2nd number, which I delineate by calling it Replicate 2) instead of the real average of 5.38